# VBA to insert rows between similar groups, add header and calculate geomean

Tags: excel, vba

I have raw data imported from text file in this form:

```
    Current table:
column1     |   column2 | column3
Data        |   Value1  | Value2
case1_int_a |   1       | 0.76
case1_int_b |   2       | 1.24
case1_fp_x  |   3       | 2.00
case1_fp_y  |   4       | 3.42
case1_fp_z  |   43      | 1.876
case2_int_c |   100     | 0.234
case3_int_d |   12      | 1
case3_int_e |   134     | 1.6

Desired Table:
column      |   column2     | column3
Data        |   Value1      | Value2
case1_int_a |   1           | 0.76
case1_int_b |   2           | 1.24
Geomean     |   = GEO(..)   | =GEO(..)

Data        | Value1    | Value2
case1_fp_x  | 3         | 2.00
case1_fp_y  | 4         | 3.42
case1_fp_z  | 43        | 1.876
Geomean     | = GEO(..) | =GEO(..)

Data        | Value1    | Value2
case2_int_c | 100       | 0.234
case3_int_d | 12        | 1
Geomean     | = GEO(..) | =GEO(..)

Data        | Value1    | Value2
case3_int_e | 134       | 1.6
Geomean     | = GEO(..) | =GEO(..)
```

I tried to use Autofilter for this but for that I need to hardcode the criteria and since there are many different types of groups, there should be some other way in which I can compare only the first 9 characters of Column A and then insert blank rows. I hope the problem is clear. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This should output what you want. Not very elegant, but should get job done. Data has to be from Cell A1 down. Outputs to Columns F to H.

```
Sub CleanUp()
Dim Row1(3) As String
Dim DataValue() As String
Dim ColumnNum As Integer
Dim DataRange As Range
Dim ValueValues()
Dim Partition() As Integer


ColumnNum = Application.CountA(Range("A:A")) - 1
ReDim DataValue(ColumnNum)
ReDim ValueValues(3, ColumnNum)

Set DataRange = Range("A2:A" & ColumnNum + 1)

Row1(1) = Range("A1").Value
Row1(2) = Range("B1").Value
Row1(3) = Range("C1").Value

i = 0
s = 0

'Populate arrays
ReDim Preserve Partition(1)
Partition(1) = 1

s = 1

For Each cell In DataRange.Cells
    i = i + 1
    DataValue(i) = Left(cell.Value, Len(cell.Value) - 2)
    If i > 1 Then
        If DataValue(i) <> DataValue(i - 1) Then
            s = s + 1
            ReDim Preserve Partition(s + 1)
            Partition(s) = i
        End If
    End If
    ValueValues(1, i) = cell.Value
    ValueValues(2, i) = cell.Offset(0, 1).Value
    ValueValues(3, i) = cell.Offset(0, 2).Value
Next cell

'Output
n = 0
t = -2

Partition(s + 1) = ColumnNum + 1

For m = 2 To s + 1
    t = t + 3
    i = 0
    num = t
    Cells(num, 5).Value = Row1(1)
    Cells(num, 6).Value = Row1(2)
    Cells(num, 7).Value = Row1(3)
    For n = Partition(m - 1) To Partition(m) - 1
        i = i + 1
        Cells(num + i, 5).Value = ValueValues(1, n)
        Cells(num + i, 6).Value = ValueValues(2, n)
        Cells(num + i, 7).Value = ValueValues(3, n)
        t = t + 1
    Next n
    Cells(t + 1, 5).Value = "Geomean"
    Cells(t + 1, 6).Formula = "=GEOMEAN(F" & t - i + 1 & ":F" & t & ")"
    Cells(t + 1, 7).Formula = "=GEOMEAN(G" & t - i + 1 & ":G" & t & ")"
Next m



End Sub
```

Comment: Whoops just realised you said first 9 characters (I was just taking off the last 2). In which case change this line

`DataValue(i) = Left(cell.Value, Len(cell.Value) - 2)`

to this

`DataValue(i) = Left(cell.Value, 9)`

Comment: I just worked around the problem, made another column that contains the first 9 characters as cell values and then used subtotal to regroup them.

Comment: Just thought I'd point out, while I acknowledge that the code is messy, and only works for this particular scenario (ie it is not universal), it does nevertheless work. Row 1 should be "Data - Value 1 - Value 2" as in the scenario given above. If you do not have the header row in the original data then yes, all the problems Tony Dallimore has mentioned will happen, but I made it to solve this particular problem, exactly as stated above. The code is messy, and could probably be done far better, but it _does_ work!

Answer (score 0):

I do not normally post a rival answer even if I do not like the original.  I have made an exception here for two reasons:

- I am very unhappy with the approach.
- It does not work.  Row 1 is included in every group.  The first row of a group is not included in Geomean.  The header row is not included as the first row of each group as shown in the desired output.

---

If you are not sure how to complete a task like this, break it into small steps.  Write a macro for step 1.  When that is working, update the macro for steps 1 and 2.  And so on.  The advantages of this approach include:

- A small step is easier to code.
- It is normally easy to find an existing question and answer that matches a small step.

The first step here is to identify the groups.  Macro `Split1` identifies the groups and outputs their details to the Immediate Window.  For your sample data, the output is:

```
Group case1_int from row 2 to 3
Group case1_fp_ from row 4 to 6
Group case2_int from row 7 to 7
Group case3_int from row 8 to 9
```

Please note, my third and fourth groups are different from yours.

Macro `Split2` builds on `Split1`.  It copies the source header and each group to the destination area and adds a totals row.

```
Option Explicit
Sub Split1()

  Dim PrefixCrnt As String
  Dim RowSrcCrnt As Long
  Dim RowSrcGrpStart As Long

  With Worksheets("Source")

    RowSrcGrpStart = 2        ' Assumes one header row
    PrefixCrnt = Mid(.Cells(RowSrcGrpStart, 1).Value, 1, 9)
    RowSrcCrnt = RowSrcGrpStart + 1

    Do While True
      If PrefixCrnt <> Mid(.Cells(RowSrcCrnt, 1).Value, 1, 9) Then
        ' Current group finished
        Debug.Print "Group " & PrefixCrnt & " from row " & RowSrcGrpStart & " to " & RowSrcCrnt - 1
        If .Cells(RowSrcCrnt, 1).Value = "" Then
          Exit Do
        End If
        RowSrcGrpStart = RowSrcCrnt
        PrefixCrnt = Mid(.Cells(RowSrcGrpStart, 1).Value, 1, 9)
        RowSrcCrnt = RowSrcGrpStart + 1
      Else
        ' Current group not finished
        RowSrcCrnt = RowSrcCrnt + 1
      End If
    Loop

  End With

End Sub
Sub Split2()

  ' Define number of columns as constant.  I do not think this makes the code
  ' more complicated and it allows for any future addition of a new column
  Const NumCols As Long = 3

  Dim ColDestCrnt As Long
  Dim ColDestStart As Long
  Dim PrefixCrnt As String
  Dim RngHdr As Range
  Dim RngSrc As Range
  Dim RowDestCrnt As Long
  Dim RowDestGrpStart As Long
  Dim RowDestStart As Long
  Dim RowSrcCrnt As Long
  Dim RowSrcGrpStart As Long
  Dim WshtDest As Worksheet

  ' Define the start point for the output which can be the same or a different
  ' worksheet and can be point within the worksheet providing the input and
  ' output ranges do not overlap.  By setting this variables her, it becomes
  ' easy to change them if necessary.  You could have successive days across the
  ' page or under the previous day's output just be changing these variables.

  Set WshtDest = Worksheets("Source")    ' Values for test 2
  ColDestStart = 6
  RowDestStart = 5

  'Set WshtDest = Worksheets("Dest")    ' Values for test 1
  'ColDestStart = 1
  'RowDestStart = 1

  RowDestCrnt = RowDestStart

  With Worksheets("Source")

    ' Assumes one header row
    Set RngHdr = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, NumCols))
    RowSrcGrpStart = 2

    PrefixCrnt = Mid(.Cells(RowSrcGrpStart, 1).Value, 1, 9)
    RowSrcCrnt = RowSrcGrpStart + 1

    Do While True
      If PrefixCrnt <> Mid(.Cells(RowSrcCrnt, 1).Value, 1, 9) Then
        ' Current group finished
        ' Debug.Print "Group " & PrefixCrnt & " from row " & RowSrcGrpStart & " to " & RowSrcCrnt - 1
        Set RngSrc = .Range(.Cells(RowSrcGrpStart, 1), _
                            .Cells(RowSrcCrnt - 1, NumCols))
        ' Copy header for group
        RngHdr.Copy WshtDest.Cells(RowDestCrnt, ColDestStart)
        RowDestCrnt = RowDestCrnt + 1
        ' Needed for totals row
        RowDestGrpStart = RowDestCrnt
        ' Copy group
        RngSrc.Copy WshtDest.Cells(RowDestCrnt, ColDestStart)
        RowDestCrnt = RowDestCrnt + RowSrcCrnt - RowSrcGrpStart
        ' Build totals row
        WshtDest.Cells(RowDestCrnt, ColDestStart).Value = "Geomean"
        For ColDestCrnt = ColDestStart + 1 To ColDestStart + NumCols - 1
          WshtDest.Cells(RowDestCrnt, ColDestCrnt).Value = _
            "=Geomean(" & ColNumToCode(ColDestCrnt) & RowDestGrpStart & ":" & _
                          ColNumToCode(ColDestCrnt) & RowDestCrnt - 1 & ")"
        Next
        RowDestCrnt = RowDestCrnt + 2
        If .Cells(RowSrcCrnt, 1).Value = "" Then
          Exit Do
        End If
        RowSrcGrpStart = RowSrcCrnt
        PrefixCrnt = Mid(.Cells(RowSrcGrpStart, 1).Value, 1, 9)
        RowSrcCrnt = RowSrcGrpStart + 1
      Else
        ' Current group not finished
        RowSrcCrnt = RowSrcCrnt + 1
      End If
    Loop

  End With

End Sub
Function ColNumToCode(ByVal ColNum As Long) As String

  Dim Code As String
  Dim PartNum As Long

  ' Last updated 3 Feb 12.  Adapted to handle three character codes.
  If ColNum = 0 Then
    ColNumToCode = "0"
  Else
    Code = ""
    Do While ColNum > 0
      PartNum = (ColNum - 1) Mod 26
      Code = Chr(65 + PartNum) & Code
      ColNum = (ColNum - PartNum - 1) \ 26
    Loop
  End If

  ColNumToCode = Code

End Function
```

Comment: Ok so I managed to get the format I wanted but I am still stuck on the Geomean part.

Comment: @user3716217  I repeat: What is wrong with the Geomean part?